# Pandas Taking a CSV and combining/concatenating rows from a previously pivoted csv

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

All I have a simple objective.

I have a CSV that has thousands of columns and thousands of rows.  I want to take the existing CSV and literally concatenate/combine the values ONLY from Rows 1 & Row 2 into one single row similar to below.  The key thing to keep in mind is that some of the values like "lion, tiger, bear repeat several times once for each metric).  I do not want it to display lion.1 , lion.2 etc , it should just display lion.

Data sample for Rows 1 and 2:

```
flow               color        desc    lion  tiger  bear  lion  tiger  bear
flow               color        desc     m1     m1    m1    m2     m2     m2       
flavor1 catego1     flavor1    catego1   32     23    34    34     21     24
flavor2 catego2     flavor2    catego2   32     23    34    34     21     24
```

How I want date to appear in CSV in Row 1 (note we need row 2 to NOT appear in the file after we combine them):

```
"flow flow"       "color color"  "desc desc"    "lion m1"  "tiger m1"  "bear m1"  "lion m2"  `“tiger m2” “bear m2”
"flavor1 catego1"    flavor1        catego1        32           23        34           34         21        24
"flavor1 catego2"    flavor2        catego2        32           23        34           34         21        24
```

Sad code attempt:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r"C:Test.csv")
row_one = df.iloc[0]
spacer = " "
row_two = df.iloc[1]
new_header = row_one+spacer+row_two
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated based on new information.

I'm assuming you haven't included the row index in your output and so I've got what works for my small dateset and I think it would work for yours.

```
import pandas as pd


def main():
    df = pd.DataFrame([['flow', 'color', 'desc'], ['flavor1 catego1', 'flavor1', 'catego1'], ['flavor2 catego2', 'flavor2', 'catego2']], columns=['flow', 'color', 'desc'])
    print('before')
    print(df)
    df = df.rename(columns={x: f'{x} {y}' for x, y in zip(df.columns, df.iloc[0])})

    print(f'Index of row to delete: {df.iloc[0].name}')
    df.drop(index=df.iloc[0].name, inplace=True)
    print()
    print('after')
    print(df)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Output

```
before
              flow    color     desc
0             flow    color     desc
1  flavor1 catego1  flavor1  catego1
2  flavor2 catego2  flavor2  catego2
Index of row to delete: 0

after
         flow flow color color desc desc
1  flavor1 catego1     flavor1   catego1
2  flavor2 catego2     flavor2   catego2
```

Comment: So I ran it, and it deletes a row, just not sure which one.  Separately, it combines what appears to be rows 2&3 and concatenates that way. without deleting the second row.  If this CSV was a previous pandas pivot to go get into this funky format, what do I do?  I'm reading from the csv after some previous transformation, the format is exactly as my original post, however when running the code, it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Is the row with `flow color desc lion tiger bear lion tiger bear` an actual row or the column names?

Comment: Column names , i.e. what appears in row 1 of the CSV.